# How to programatically add an image to a CommandButton/Form Button/Image Control

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA, and I've been learning a lot mostly from forums like Stack Overflow. I've searched over and over for a solution to this problem, and can't seem to find any... What I want to do is to have a code that, when executed, will insert a "button" in the third column of the selected row. For example, if the cell "S83" is selected, I want a "button" to appear in cell S3. I'm saying "button" because it does not matter to me wheter it's a CommandButton or a Form Button or an Image Control (from Form Controls), as long as it shows an image and perform an action when clicked. Playing around with codes I got from the forums and the Macro Recorder, I ended up with two different pieces of code. The first one manages to insert the picture, but I can't figure out how to make it perform an action when clicked:

```vb
Sub AddImageControl()
Dim t As Range
Dim btn As OLEObject
Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 3)
Set btn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=t.Left, Top:=t.Top, _
    Width:=t.Width, Height:=t.Height
With btn
    .Object.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\dummy\Pictures\Task.jpg")
    .Object.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
    .ShapeRange.Left = t.Left
    .ShapeRange.Top = t.Top
    .ShapeRange.Width = t.Width
    .ShapeRange.Height = t.Height
End With
End Sub
```

The second piece of code inserts a Form Button which allows me to perform an action that is dependent of the row where the button is (which would be extremely appreciated). But this time, I can't figure out how to insert an image in the button:

```vb
Sub AddFormsButton()
Dim sShape As Shape

Dim t As Range
Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 3)

With t
    Set sShape = Sheet1.Shapes.AddFormControl _
    (Type:=xlButtonControl, Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
End With
With sShape
    .OnAction = "test"
    .TextFrame.Characters.Caption = ""
End With

End Sub


Sub test()
MsgBox "This button is in row " & ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row + 1
End Sub
```

If anyone could help me with this issue, I would really appreciate. Please notice these are NOT CommandBar buttons nor UserForm buttons, they must be placed in the sheet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

There are two types of controls you can place on a worksheet: Form controls and ActiveX controls. They are both available on the Developer ribbon on Excel front-end.

[image: Developer Ribbon > Insert]

If you don't see Developer ribbon, right-click the ribbon, choose Customize Ribbon, and check on Developer in the list of ribbons.

ActiveX controls are much more powerful-- right-click one, click Properties, and see the many features it supports.

To answer your first question, how to add an action to the OleObject you create in your first block of code: the button you created in code is an ActiveX control. To find its event procedure, switch to Design Mode by click the Design Mode button on the Developer ribbon. Now, double-click your activeX button, and Excel will take you straight to the event-macro for that button. The event is available in the worksheet code-behind.

It's easy to put an image on an ActiveX control without all that programming effort. On Excel front-end, while in Design Mode, right-click your ActiveX button and choose Properties. You'll find the "Picture" property in there.

To answer your second question: your second example is a Form Control. Form controls are an older technology, and very simple. I'd love to find out myself how to put a picture on one :)

However, you can easily assign a macro to any image you insert directly on the sheet-- you just won't get the fancy 'push-in' animation you get with a button. On the Insert ribbon, click Picture. Choose your picture and click OK. Now right-click the picture and choose "Assign macro". This is exactly how you assign a macro to the old-school form controls-- again, no code is needed to create the control or assign a macro to it.

That should be enough to get you going.